# C# WebRequest POST returns Html page - how to display it in browser

Tags: c#, webrequest

I'm working with the SagePay payment gateway.

On a checkout button click I'm using the method below to postData (contains the transaction data) to SagePay who then return the result in the form of a html page.

```
public string SendRequest(string url, string postData)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var requestData = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Timeout = (300 * 1000); //TODO: Move timeout to config
    request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
    }

    var response = request.GetResponse();

    string result;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return result;
}
```

How do I show this returned html in the users browser window as this would be where they enter their credit card info?

Comment: Which type of SagePay integration are you using? Form, Server, or Direct?

Comment: It would be forms integration.. the integration kit provided it pretty bad.

Comment: Probably shouldn't `directly` output the results of a third-party app into your website (even if it's trusted, like SagePay). Should inspect the HTTP response, pull out the info you need into some kind of "result" model, then bind to that in your HTML. Point is, just take what you need (success/fail, info messages, etc), then customize your UI based on that info.

Comment: But what about the fact that with the forms integration you goto the SagePay pages to enter the payment info and these are the pages that the html is getting returned for on the post from the method above

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Assuming this is a Forms application, why not use a [`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control? It has a nifty property, [`DocumentStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx). Hooking it up to a stream is as simple as:</strike>

```
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
        webBrowser1.DocumentStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Maybe rewriting the doc with fully qualified URLs might help, although I suspect a payment gateway might get funny about referer (sic).

```
        string responseString;
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //consider rewriting some URLs in the response so they are fully qualified
        //in method below.
        //responseString=ProcessResponseString();
        //squirt response back to user
```

Comment: Its not a windows forms application but a web forms website

Answer (score 0):

if you're working in a Web Application(ASP.NET),you can make this:

**Markup:**

```
 <div id="HTMLResponse" runat="server"></div>
```

**ASP.NET:**

```
HTMLResponse.InnerHtml = SendRequest(...);
```